# Qt application has no focus at all on embedded device

Tags: qt, qt5

I made a Qt 5 widget application.
On desktop linux all is well. All the widgets (`QLineEdit, QComboBox` ..etc) are working as expected.

However I build this app for embedded arm linux, using EGLFS platform, without keyboard, but with a touchscreen.
(I have an onscreen keyboard, simulating keypresses)

When running on this device, there is no focus on the widgets.
I can not even set focus programatically:
`ui->lineEdit_email->setFocus();` has no effect

I tried to set some widgets focuspolicy to `Qt::StrongFocus`. No effect.

I have no idea where to look, do you?

Answer (score 0):

It was this two lines:

```
  effect_waiting = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(label_waiting_background);
  effect_waiting->setOpacity(0.5);
```

After trying to put a transparent label to the ui, it stopeed working. Must be a bug somewhere down the graphics stack...